# angular 2 draw rectangle on google map

Tags: google-maps, angular

I'm trying to draw a rectangle on google map using angular 2, but I get this

[image]

Here is the code:

```js
    var LatLngLiteralX1 = { lat: startPositionX, lng: startPositionY };
    var LatLngLiteralX2 = { lat: startPositionX, lng: startPositionY + deltaZoom };
    var LatLngLiteralX3 = { lat: startPositionX + deltaZoom, lng: startPositionY };
    var LatLngLiteralX4 = { lat: startPositionX + deltaZoom, lng: startPositionY + deltaZoom };


    var newPloygon = new Polygon(LatLngLiteralX1, LatLngLiteralX2, LatLngLiteralX3, LatLngLiteralX4);
```

```html
  <sebm-map-polygon *ngFor="let polygon of polygonPathDatas"
        [paths]="polygon.path"
        [editable]="false"
        [draggable]="false" 
        (polyClick)="click($event)" 
        (polyDblClick)="delete($event)">
      </sebm-map-polygon>
```

Comment: I think you missed `LatLngLiteralX4` here `var newPloygon = new Polygon(LatLngLiteralX1, LatLngLiteralX2, LatLngLiteralX3, LatLngLiteralX4);`

Comment: i missed it  on this snippet , result with LatLngLiteralX4 is same

Comment: Should X3 be the position you have set for X4? I don't want to add an answer in case it is wrong, and I can't test it. Rectangle should be (x, y), (x, y+d), (x+d, y+d), (x+d, y) and that's why it's crossing over in the middle on yours.

Comment: thanks that solved my problem